# DDD - Application Service location with multiple "entry points"

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Application Services in DDD are supposed to orchestrate full business use cases, using Repositories to fetch Aggregates, calling methods on the Aggregates and managing infrastructure concerns like database transactions.

When reading books from Eric Evans, Vaughn Vernon and Scott Millett, you can find great examples on how separate your projects. But I never found clear answers for this situation.

Suppose you have a Domain, and three "entry points" to communicate with this domain:

1. Rest API for synchronous actions
2. Messenger "daemon" / "service" running on the OS for asynchronous actions
3. Powershell cmdlets for administrative users for maintenance actions

where do you place those Application Services if you have one DLL per entry point for deployment purpose?

Option A: dedicated Application Service project (DLL) referenced by all entry point DLLs.

Option B: Application Services located in each entry point's DLL.

In the first option, you can benefit from code reuse when multiple entry points share the same use cases. Same thing for unit tests. However, you theoretically have to deploy an Application Service DLL having too much features for some entry points.

In the second option, you have to duplicate code (and tests) in each entry point's dll when they share the same use cases, but you can theoretically have the control on infrastructure concern like database transaction that could be different depending the execution is in a Powershell Cmdlet on in an API.

In my opinion, the real answer is a question of personal preference.

Anyone having experience with both approaches (success or failure) have some tips or recommandations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Option A: dedicated Application Service project (DLL) referenced by all entry point DLLs.

This is roughly what I would expect to see.  You have three [composition roots](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) here, that should always share the same model (to ensure that all paths enforce the current business invariant) and the same book of record (if they don't share the same book of record, they really don't need to share anything at all).

In fact, I strongly suspect that you could separate these completely -- run "the model" in a "microservice", and deploy your three interfaces above that each uses a common service client DLL to talk to that core service.

You might, for instance, review the [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).  It aligns fairly closely with the image of a single dll for the application services, with each of your compositions roots using a different interface to adapt their own API to that of the model.

> you theoretically have to deploy an Application Service DLL having too much features for some entry points.

That's so; there's a trade off there.  My guess is that in most deployments, shipping a single fat DLL is going to be more cost effective than trying to deploy multiple jars with different subsets of the same model.

Personally, I'd start with a fat microservice, a well designed API, and fat clients in each of the composition roots above, and then if necessarily replace the fat clients with thinner, more specialized ones if the trade offs support that choice.

> Just to be sure I understand one of your point. Are you suggesting that my domain (what you called "the model") should expose an API, and my different entry points (what you called "composition root") should call this API?

Yes, that's a fair description of the proposal, except I want to be more clear on the "should expose an API" part.  The API should be explicit.  That is to say, looking at the code, you should be able to point to a seam in your code where the separation of concerns happens

- *This* part is where the model lives
- *That* part is where the specialization lives

Your option B is (provided you make the seam explicit) is this idea within a single library.  Your option A is this idea, with seam as the interface between two libraries (still running in the same process).  Microservices is this idea, with the two libraries running in different processes.

You get different tradeoffs - for instance, if the model runs in a dedicated microservice, then (a) changing the model is "easy", because there's exactly one authority to swap out, and (b) you now have the freedom to implement your specialized interfaces in any technology that can exchange messages with your domain service, (c) you can also scale out the model independently of how you scale out the specializations.

But you also get additional complexity, in that you need to think more about the stability of the API when the client and server have independent deployment cycles.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand one of your point. Are you suggesting that my domain (what you called "the model") should expose an API, and my different entry points (what you called "composition root") should call this API?

So in this particular case, I'd have a Powershell cmdlet calling the API of the microservice and a "daemon" handling the message queuing concerns calling the API of the microservice?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason The "model in a microservice" sound interesting. Would be nice if you wrote a (blog) article about it or if you had any further links.